# AWS file gateway performance

Tags: amazon-web-services

We started using AWS file gateway 2 months ago. And then we received an AWS maintenance update. File writes of around 17kB started taking 14-20 seconds, which blocked our main haproxy load balancer causing request timeouts and finally system went down. 
We switched back to our local NFS to resolve this problem temporarily.
After that we started running load on our local NFS mount vs AWS file gateway mount. And all our load tests show that for 100req/sec file write load (file_size=17kb)

- AWS file gateway mount takes on an average - 20secs for each file
  write
- Our local NFS is taking - 20millisecs for each file write

If i compare only single cp into local NFS mount vs AWS file gateway mount :
 - AWS file gateway mount takes on an average - 60millisecs for each file
   write 
 - Our local NFS is taking - 20millisecs for each file write

**AWS file gateway mount**

```
[root@loadtest-app ~]# start=`date +%s%N`;sudo cp /tmp/1A9E_U8VY6AAOYP.html /kfiles/load_test/2018/01/04/TP58_MNOUGFL5NX.html;end=`date +%s%N`;echo `expr $end - $start`
```

63052453 microseconds

**Our local NFS**

```
[root@loadtest-app ~]# start=`date +%s%N`;sudo cp /tmp/1A9E_U8VY6AAOYP.html /files/load_test/2018/01/04/TP58_MNOUGFL5NX.html;end=`date +%s%N`;echo `expr $end - $start`
```

19005490 microseconds

At load AWS file gateway mount average time increase to 20secs.

We have been in touch with AWS tech support, and at their end all metrics looks ok to them.
We have been waiting for their AWS service team to debug this issue for us. I wonder anyone has encountered this recently.